# Core files from restored package is missing in resulted Artifact in Azure DevOps PipeLine

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, devops, umbraco, azure-devops-pipelines

In the task "Visual Studio Build" in my Azure DevOps pipeline, I found it processes one of my third party package (called Umbraco)in a stage called "Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Stage PipelineMsdeploySpecificTransformPhase", which runs after "PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder". Therefore, the final Artifact does not include these Umbraco core files.

I am wondering what is this "PipelineMsdeploySpecificTransformPhase", why VS Build task copies Umbraco package at this staging? Is there a way to control it?

Below is the task log - web file system publish is before the Umbraco files are copied over.

[image]
[image]

Below is my Visual Studio Build task setup - I am trying to publish it as files rather than zip packages
[image]

I am new to StackOverflow, hope my question makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to use copy files task to copy your Umbraco package manually before publishing artifacts.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT Thanks for your suggestion, It does not seem to suit my case. I checked "Copy File" task copies files from the source folder, but these Umbraco packages are not included in the source control but generate from "Virtual Studio Build" task.